# My insertion sort is not giving desired result and i am not able to figure out

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

i was trying to perform insertion sort on a doubly linked list and before anyone suggest that i should use sorted insertion i know it can be done but it is not allowed for the work.
here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DLinkedList {

    private class Node {
        private int value;
        private Node nextNode;
        private Node prevNode;

        public Node(int v) {
            value = v;
            nextNode = null;
            prevNode = null;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int v) {
            value = v;
        }

        public Node getNextNode() {
            return nextNode;
        }

        public void setNextNode(Node n) {
            nextNode = n;
        }

        public Node getPrevNode() {
            return prevNode;
        }

        public void setPrevNode(Node n) {
            prevNode = n;
        }

    }

    // Holds a reference to the head and tail of the list
    private Node headNode;
    private Node tailNode;

    public DLinkedList() {
        headNode = null;
        tailNode = null;
    }

    public Object getHeadValue() {
        if (headNode == null)
            return null;
        return headNode.value;
    }

    public Object getTailValue() {
        if (tailNode == null)
            return null;
        return tailNode.value;
    }

    public void addAtHead(int o) {
        Node newNode = new Node(o);
        newNode.setNextNode(headNode);
        if (headNode != null)
            headNode.setPrevNode(newNode);
        headNode = newNode;
        // special case for empty list
        if (tailNode == null)
            tailNode = newNode;
    }

    public void addAtTail(int o) {
        Node newNode = new Node(o);
        // this means that headNode == null too!
        if (tailNode == null) {
            tailNode = newNode;
            headNode = newNode;
        } else {
            newNode.setPrevNode(tailNode);
            tailNode.setNextNode(newNode);
            tailNode = newNode;
        }
    }

    public int deleteAtHead() {
        // list is empty
        if (headNode == null) {
            headNode = null;
            tailNode = null;
            return -1;
        }
        // singleton: must update tailnode too
        if (headNode == tailNode) {
            int res = headNode.getValue();
            headNode = null;
            tailNode = null;
            return res;
        }

        int res = headNode.getValue();
        headNode = headNode.getNextNode();
        headNode.setPrevNode(null);
        return res;
    }

    public int deleteAtTail() {
        // list is empty
        if (tailNode == null) {
            headNode = null;
            tailNode = null;
            return -1;
        }
        // singleton: must update tailnode too
        if (headNode == tailNode) {
            int res = tailNode.getValue();
            headNode = null;
            tailNode = null;
            return res;
        }
        int res = tailNode.getValue();
        tailNode = tailNode.getPrevNode();
        tailNode.setNextNode(null);
        return res;
    }

    public int delete(Node n) {
        if (n == null)
            return -1;
        Node next = n.getNextNode();
        Node prev = n.getPrevNode();
        int val = n.getValue();
        if (prev != null)
            prev.setNextNode(next);
        if (next != null)
            next.setPrevNode(prev);
        // deleting at the end
        if (n == tailNode)
            tailNode = prev;
        // deleteing at beginning
        if (n == headNode)
            headNode = next;
        return val;
    }

    public void insertAfter(Node n, int val) {
        if (n == null) { // this is the headNode
            addAtHead(val);
            return;
        }
        Node next = n.getNextNode();
        Node newNode = new Node(val);
        newNode.setPrevNode(n);
        newNode.setNextNode(next);
        n.setNextNode(newNode);
        if (next == null) { // insert at tail
            tailNode = newNode;
        } else {
            next.setPrevNode(newNode);
        }
    }

    // computes the size of the list
    public int size() {
        if (headNode == null)
            return 0;
        Node n = headNode;
        int size = 0;
        while (n != null) {
            size++;
            n = n.getNextNode();
        }
        return size;
    }

    // Predicate to check if the linked list is sorted
    public boolean isSorted() {
        if (headNode == null || headNode.nextNode == null)
            return true;
        Node i = headNode.nextNode;
        while (i != null) {
            if (i.getValue() < i.getPrevNode().getValue())
                return false;
            i = i.nextNode;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // toString methods to override printing of object
    public String toString() {
        Node n = headNode;
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        while (n != null) {
            buf.append(n.getValue());
            buf.append(" ");
            n = n.getNetNode();
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

    public void insertionSort(DLinkedList arr) {
        Node current=arr.headNode.getNextNode();
        while(current!=null)
        {
            Node nextNode=current.getNextNode();
            Node searchNode=current.prevNode;
            
            while(searchNode!=null && searchNode.getValue()>current.getValue())
            {
                searchNode=searchNode.prevNode;
            }
            
            delete(current);
            
            if(searchNode==null) {
                current.prevNode=null;
                addAtHead(current.getValue());
            }
            
            else {
                insertAfter(searchNode,searchNode.getValue());
            }
            current=nextNode;
            
            
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DLinkedList d = new DLinkedList();
        d.addAtHead(4);
        d.addAtHead(1);
        d.addAtHead(7);
        d.addAtHead(10);
        d.addAtHead(101);
        System.out.println("Before sorting: " + d); // this will call the toString method
        d.insertionSort(d);
        System.out.println("After sorting: " + d);
    }

}
```

the list i provided is 101 10 7 1 4
and the list after sorting comes 1 1 7 10 101
i have been scratching my head for days but can't figure it out

Function you all need to look at is

```
public void insertionSort(DLinkedList arr)
```

Comment: In `addAtHead` assign the old head to the tail, not the new node. Writing down the state of the list on paper may help resolve any other issues

Comment: i don't see problem in addAtHead as it works correctly only the sorting part is bugging